# python cursor.execute(query, arg) : passing a list as an argument

Tags: python, sql, list, input, cursor

Basically I need to input a list in a query.
It works very well with strings only but nut lists.

```
cursor.execute('select * from nicknames where name = %;', ('Smith', ))
```

So this one works, but then when I want to do the same with two names, then nothing.

```
cursor.execute('select * from nicknames where name in %s', ('(Smith, Andy)', ))
```

Do you know how I can make such a query ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can format it with the brackets inside the query like so:

```
cursor.execute('select * from nicknames where name in (%s, %s)', ("Smith", "Andy"))
```